# Print float numbers

Tags: java, android

I am creating Android app and I need to print float number with textView. Could someone say which function should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
//Retrieve the TextView and set the text
Float yourFloat = 1.0;
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
textView.setText(yourFloat.toString());
```

Comment: Of course, in that case you run into the problem of 0.1*0.2 being 0.0200000000000004. You should really be using a Formatter and setting the precision in the pattern

Answer (score 2):

I guess all you need is a standard java language `Formatter` (in case you need to take locale into account):
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, you'll need to convert your float to a String first:

```
float f = 42.0;
textView.setText(String.valueOf(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
textView.setText("" + 1.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
EditText text =(EditText)findViewById(id);
text.setText(Float.toString(f));
```

where f is your variable.